# How to continue running the script even if you don't have access to the Google Site?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to get the owners, viewers and editors of a classic google sites. How do I code this to continue running the script if either, I don't have access to the google sites or the URL is invalid?

Also, do you know if I used the method - getOwners, getViewers, getEditors will display the respective email addresses?

Here is my partial code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheetVal.length-1; i++) {
    var sitesURL = sheetVal[i][0];
    var owners = sheetVal[i][1];
    var viewers = sheetVal[i][2];
    var editors = sheetVal[i][3];
    
    if (owners && viewers && editors != "") {continue;}
    else {
      
      var array = [];
      
      var sites = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(sitesURL);
      var data = [
        sites.getOwners().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
        sites.getViewers().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
        sites.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(",")
      ];
          
      array.push(data);
      AL.getRange(i+2,2,array.length,array[0].length).setValue(array);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you use a "try-catch" statement so that in case your method fails, your script doesn't stop execution?

Comment: Instead of partial code a [mcve] is required and each post should include only one question.

Comment: @ Da Mahdi03, I did change and tried the try-catch statement but the script still stops and logs the error in the sheet. I'd like the script to continue running even if it catches and logs the error.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheetVal.length - 1; i++) {
  var sitesURL = sheetVal[i][0];
  var owners = sheetVal[i][1];
  var viewers = sheetVal[i][2];
  var editors = sheetVal[i][3];

  if (owners && viewers && editors) {
    var array = [];
    var sites = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(sitesURL);
    var data = [
      sites.getOwners().map(function (e) { return [e.getEmail()] }).join(","),
      sites.getViewers().map(function (e) { return [e.getEmail()] }).join(","),
      sites.getEditors().map(function (e) { return [e.getEmail()] }).join(",")
    ];
    array.push(data);
    AL.getRange(i + 2, 2, array.length, array[0].length).setValue(array);
  }else{
    continue;
  }
  }
}
```